# Hibernate filter for get update delete operation?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-filters

I am using hibernate filter for one of my application.
Intention is to use hibernate filter in crud operation.
Hibernate filter is working fine with select query but 
it is not adding where clause in update delete get operation even after enabling of filter in session.

Here below is my code 
Employee.java, where I added a filter on tenantFilter.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "tenantId", type = "string"))
@Filters(@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_id=:tenantId"))
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name = "cell_phone")
    private String cellphone;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private String tenant_id;

    public Employee() {

    }

    public Employee(String firstname, String lastname, Date birthdate,
            String phone, String tenant) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.birthDate = birthdate;
        this.cellphone = phone;
        this.tenant_id = tenant;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public String getCellphone() {
        return cellphone;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public void setCellphone(String cellphone) {
        this.cellphone = cellphone;
    }

    public String getTenant() {
        return tenant_id;
    }

    public void setTenant(String tenant) {
        this.tenant_id = tenant;
    }

}
```

For list api (as below) filter is working fine

```
private static List list() {
        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.enableFilter("tenantFilter").setParameter("tenantId", "visa");
        List employees = session.createQuery("from Employee").list();
        session.close();
        return employees;
    }
```

Hibernate query for list api with where clause

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        employee0_.id as id0_,
        employee0_.birth_date as birth2_0_,
        employee0_.cell_phone as cell3_0_,
        employee0_.firstname as firstname0_,
        employee0_.lastname as lastname0_,
        employee0_.tenant_id as tenant6_0_ 
    from
        EMPLOYEE employee0_ 
    where
        employee0_.tenant_id=?
```

For read api (as below) filter is not applying

```
private static Employee read(Long id) {
        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.enableFilter("tenantFilter").setParameter("tenantId", "visa");
        Employee employee = (Employee) session.get(Employee.class, id);
        session.close();
        return employee;
    }
```

Hiberbernate query for read api

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        employee0_.id as id0_0_,
        employee0_.birth_date as birth2_0_0_,
        employee0_.cell_phone as cell3_0_0_,
        employee0_.firstname as firstname0_0_,
        employee0_.lastname as lastname0_0_,
        employee0_.tenant_id as tenant6_0_0_ 
    from
        EMPLOYEE employee0_ 
    where
        employee0_.id=?
```

Same for update api (as below) filter is not applying

```
private static Employee update(Employee employee) {
        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.enableFilter("tenantFilter").setParameter("tenantId", "visa");
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.merge(employee);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return employee;
    }
```

Hibernate query for read api

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        employee0_.id as id0_0_,
        employee0_.birth_date as birth2_0_0_,
        employee0_.cell_phone as cell3_0_0_,
        employee0_.firstname as firstname0_0_,
        employee0_.lastname as lastname0_0_,
        employee0_.tenant_id as tenant6_0_0_ 
    from
        EMPLOYEE employee0_ 
    where
        employee0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        EMPLOYEE 
    set
        birth_date=?,
        cell_phone=?,
        firstname=?,
        lastname=?,
        tenant_id=? 
    where
        id=?
```

Same for delete api also filter is not applying.

I searched hibernate filter documentation for crud operation but not able to get any description on it.
So is it right to apply filter for crud operation or I am assuming it wrong.
Please assist.
I want to achieve multi tenancy environment using filter where single database is serving multiple tenancies.

Comment: Did you solve this ? I'm looking exactly for the same solution

Comment: I want this solution to target multi-tenancy in my application. But the hibernate version we used is not capable of that. So we used composite keys to in where condition. But I read somewhere the hibernate upper version (not sure about version) will support multi-tenancy. Thanks,

Comment: @SanjayJain , did you find solution?